# How to solve server certificate verification failed?

Tags: authentication, certificate, ssl-certificate, clone, git-clone

Recently I installed a complete ubuntu package on **virtualbox** and use it via **vagrant ssh** in windows.from yesterday i have a annoying problem,I cant use sudo commands for install,update or everything and when i use it triggers the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists
/trustybackports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 127.8.0.12 80]  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 127.8.0.12 80]
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

already this is not the single point for me.when i want to use git clone from the url like:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic quickstart
```

it triggers the following error:

```
Cloning into 'quick'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-
intermediate/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

and if use the following command:

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

then clone from the git it triggers the following error:

```
Cloning into 'quick'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-intermediate/' not found
```

Also i don't have "**sudo dpkg**" to use.
i have no idea why did this problem happen?!!!and i've seen askubuntu and git and every search result of google but i couldn't solve my problem.
also i don't know what should i do in cert directory if it's necessary to do?
if there is anyone who could help me it would be awesome.